# Show authorizations according to situations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I have Employee and this have authorizations. How to show only authorizations with situation 1 and 6.
this is my code:

```
if employee.authorizations.situation == 1 
(...)
elsif employee.authorizations.situation == 6
(...)
```

But, ever return false, but I have in my database 3 authorizations situation 1, and 2 authorizations situation 6.

In console, when I enter employee.authorizations.first.situation == 1, retunr true. Same thing for situation 6.

What is my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete answer

```
employee.authorizations.where(situation: 1).exist?
```

Comment: There's also `.any?` which might explain things better. Both methods are valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a collection by some property:

```
employee.authorizations.where(situation: 1)
```

Comment: don't work, in my view I do: <% if employee.authorizations.where(situation: 1), else employee.authorizations.where(situation: 6), but continue show all...

Comment: @EltonSantos It's a scope that will always return a *truthful* value. As you note in your answer you need to do something with it, like test vs. `.count` or `.any?`